# Unable to compile java class that extends a class in a JAR file

Tags: android, jar

I am trying to create a JAR file that will include all my main common files which I can inlucde into all my android applications. I cannot compile the code for the following errors:

- Error: Could not find or load main class Student
- Student.java:4: error: cannot find symbol public class Student extends Person {

Here's what I do:

I created a folder /home/erikt/app/mylib/ to store all my java classes.

Person.java

```
package com.mylib;

public class Person {

public String name;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  }

public Person(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}

public String toString() {
  return name;
}
}
```

Manifest.mf

```
Manifest-version: 1.0
Main-Class: Person
```

Then I run:

```
javac com/mylib/Person.java
jar cvfm mylib.jar manifest.mf com/mylib/*.class
```

I get:

```
added manifest
adding: com/mylib/Person.class(in = 427) (out= 273)(deflated 36%)
```

The content of mylib.jar

```
  META-INF/
  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  com/mylib/Person.class
```

Now here's my problem:

path: /home/erikt/app/mytest/

```
cd /home/erikt/app/mytest/
cp ../mylib/mylib.jar .
```

Student.java

```
package com.mytest;
import com.mylib;

public class Student extends Person {
  public String somethingnew;

  public Student(String name) {
    super(name);
    somethingnew = "surprise!";
  }

  public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "\t" + somethingnew;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person you = new Person("foo");
    Student me = new Student("boo");

    System.out.println("Your name is " + you);
    System.out.println("My name is " + me);
  }
}
```

Compile:

javac -classpath . -cp ./mylib.jar Student.java

I get:

```
$ javac -classpath . -cp ./mylib.jar Student.java

Student.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public class Student extends Person {

                         ^
```

or if i try:

```
$ java Student
Error: Could not find or load main class Student
```

Comment: You are adding "-classpath . -cp ./mylib.jar" to the javac, do the same for the java! `java -classpath . -cp ./mylib.jar Student`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, (i also removed the package)